# Keep options list static in Semantic UI multiple search select dropdown

Tags: reactjs, select, search, dropdown, semantic-ui

As it works now, the multiple search select dropdown allows a user to search for an item contained within the options list, and once selected, removes the option from being able to be selected again. I'd like to be able to keep that option available.

I'd like to keep the options list static when a user clicks on an item in the multiple search select dropdown.

My findings so far:
It appears the options list contained with the event object does not change when a user selects an item from the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. [All the selected values are filtered out of the menu options in a multi select `Dropdown`](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/modules/Dropdown/Dropdown.js#L778-L780).